# How can I get the number of member variables of a struct in c++?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a struct with 3 member variables. I would like to have a function that would take the struct either as a parameter or a template parameter and return the number of member variables (Should work with any struct that is plain old data).

```cpp
struct S
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;
};

template<class Struct>
std::size_t GetSize(const Struct& S);

void foo()
{
    S a(1, 2.0f, 'c');
    std::cout << GetSize(a) << std::endl;
    // This code should print 3, since there are 3 member variables inside the struct.
}
```

Comment: Short answer - you can't. Not until reflection becomes part of the language.

Comment: This is called "introspection" and C++ is really bad at it. Use that as a search term to find out more.

Comment: Handy reading: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: use [magic get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)'s `boost::pfr::tuple_size<S>::value`